# How do you create a formatted string like the following in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm a newcomer to the iPhone world. (Previously, I've developed for android.)

I've got this code in one of my Android apps:

```
String body = "<Item type='Customer' id= '"+id+"'  action='delete'/>";
```

What's the same in Objective-C?

Comment: Would you mind spelling your words properly? I'm sure your favorite spell checker would love to help.

Comment: Objective-C and Java aren't very similar languages, other than the C/C-like core.  Are you sure you're ready for this?  I'd expect a mechanical, or piece by piece translation, to have serious problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `-[NSString stringWithFormat:]`:

```
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Item type='Customer' id='%@' action='delete'/>", idNum];
```

Assuming the ID is stored in the variable `idNum`. (`id` is actually a type in Objective-C, so you don't want to use that as a variable name.)

Comment: Nor do you want %@ as a format specifier for something that's probably a C integer type.  It's OK if idNum is an NSNumber.

Answer (score 1):

As Henrik says, it's:

```
NSInteger id = 5;
NSString* body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Item type='Customer' id= '%d'  action='delete'/>", i];
```

(A purist may argue with this, though.)

But really the answer is to read through "[Learning Objective-C: A Primer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/)." It's not terribly long and shows you pretty much everything you need to know about the language.

Comment: I prefer Henrik's version because the pointer sign is near the variable, which is much clearer when having something like `int value, *pointer;` On the other hand, I agree with you that he needs to learn Objective-C by reading a book.

Comment: I changed the answer to reflect the fact that the question was altered.

Comment: @Georg, this is something I change my opinion on every couple of years! This years take is that the pointery-ness of a variable is part of the type. I tend to list variables declarations on separate lines anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
String body = "<Item type='Customer' id= '"+id+"'  action='delete'/>";


NSString* id = @"foo";
NSString* body 
  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Item type='Customer' id='%@' action='delete'/>", id ];
```